# How to use find function on map/unordered_map in multi-thread programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I read somewhere saying `find()` is not thread safe on STL `map` because when other thread is inserting to the map, the map itself is re-balancing, so `find()` may not return the proper iterator even the entry is indeed in the map. My observation tends to echo this. How about hash map (`unordered_map`)? I fear it may have the same issue, but not clear why.

So what is the proper way to call `find()` in a multithreaded context or is there any replacement?

example can be:

```
std::map<int, std::string> the_map;
```

in thread 1:

```
// Step1
_mutex.lock();
the_map[1] = "this";
_mutex.unlock();

...
// Step3
if (the_map.find(1) == the_map.end()) {
    throw("Cannot find!");
}
```

in thread 2

```
// Step2
_mutex.lock();
the_map[2] = "that";
_mutex.unlock();
```

If step 2 and 3 are taking places concurrently, then step 3 could be disrupted.

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than manual locking and unlocking, consider using a RAII wrapper like `std::lock_guard` or `std::scoped_lock` to ensure proper unlocking in the event of the unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*None* of the standard library containers are threadsafe.  If you want to do this kind of thing, you must protect *all* accesses (both read and write) by a mutex.

Comment: If I use mutex to protect find(), does this synchronize the insertion on the other thread?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is the same one.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the mutex for calling `find` so that no one can write to the map while your find call is executing. This goes for any non threadsafe container or structure, you have to protect it often from reading and writing simultaneously. `Find` is reading. It doesnt matter whether you are using std::find on a vector, a list, map, unordered_map, or somethign else. Unless the container is threadsafe you must provide the protection yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.